# Problems of use top.Ext4.window.Window declaration in ExtJs 4.2 sandbox mode

Tags: javascript, extjs4.2

I'm using ExtJS 4.2 in sandbox mode, the included js file is ext-all-sandbox.js.
Below code runs good：

```js
 var myWindow = new Ext4.window.Window({
  id : 'myId',
  title : 'my title',
  width : 890,
  height : 650,
  resizable :false,
  modal : true,
  border : false,
  plain : true,
  layout : 'fit',
  items : [ form ]
 });
 
 myWindow.show();
```

But if change the code to ：

```js
var myWindow = new top.Ext4.window.Window({
  id : 'myId',
  title : 'my title',
  width : 890,
  height : 650,
  resizable :false,
  modal : true,
  border : false,
  plain : true,
  layout : 'fit',
  items : [ form ]
 });
 
 myWindow.show();
```

There's an error:
"SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'window': object is null or undefined" .

Declaration of "top.Ext.window.Window" runs ok,but "top.Ext4.window.Window"
runs error,these codes runs inside an iframe, and i want the window to show outside of iframe, so i add a "top" prefix.

I found the problem occurs because ExtJS4.2 and ExtJS2.0 code in the same page. The error occurs inside extjs2.0's js file. If i do not include extjs 2.0 file(ext-all.js), top.Ext4.window.Window runs ok.

But i cannot remove the source codes writing in ExtJS 2.0 ,because the upgrading work is huge, is there a way to make the mixed codes run?
Thanks in advance.